# Changing sentence inside a printf

Tags: c

i'm new to C and i have these line of codes

```
int Input(char c) 
{
    printf("input number %c: ",c);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return a;
}
```

```
void main()
{
    int n;
    n = Input('A'); // n = a ;
    printf("The number you just input is %d", n); 
    return;
}
```

***Output:***

`Input number A:` 5

`The number you just input is` 5

But i'm wondering if i can replace the `"input number %c: "` which another string like `"input a number above 0"` using the called function in **main()**

```
int Input(char c) 
{
    printf("%s: ",c);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    return a;
}
```

```
void main()
{
    int n;
    n = Input("input a number above 0: ");
    printf("The number you just input is %d", n); 
    return;
}
```

***Expected Output:***

`input a number above 0: *input a number*`

Comment: I can see at least two reasons why your code doesn't compile. Please fix it before we go any further.

Comment: pass a `char*` instead of `char`, use `%s` instead of `%c`, and call it using double quotes not single

Comment: and always test the return from `scanf`

Comment: i did use ``char*`` but still won't work

Comment: Suggestion: turn on all your compiler warnings. **Mind those warnings!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `a` is undefined in your `Input` function.

As for passing a string instead of a single character:

`%c` expects a `char`.

`%s` expects a `char *` - a pointer to a null-terminated [*string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Remember to check that the return value of `scanf` matches the *number of conversions* you were expecting, and handle the event otherwise (e.g., [`exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)).

```
int Input(const char *msg) {
    int val;
    
    printf("input number %s", msg);
    
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &val)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read integer value.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    return val;        
}
```

Usage:

```
int n = Input("a string");
```

---

If you want to retain string interpolation, use a variadic function.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_int(const char *msg, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vprintf(msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    int val;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &val)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read integer value.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return val;
}

int main(void) {
    int n = get_int("Enter an integer (%c): ", 'A');

    printf("Got: %d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, i didn't define ``a`` because i already did in another file.cpp and too lazy to write them all down on here.
 
Secondly, i just copied a piece of the code onto here cause i was just wondering if i could change that ``Input`` function not because it didn't compile.

Thirdly, thank you for the answer, it's super helpful :)

Comment: @KelvinĐại In the future, please provide a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question -- otherwise we will take your *broken* example (and by extension, your level of understanding) at face value.